# How do I return all characters that begin and end with certain characters in Perl (Or C++)?

Tags: c++, string, perl, input, io

**note:** I'm running Perl 5 on Linux

I'm currently doing a project where I have to input a few words and then return words that begin with "d" and end with "e". I'm not using a pre-done list, for example I input into the console *Done, Dish, Dome, and Death*. I want it to return *Done and Dome*, but not the other words. I hope to receive help how to do this in Perl, but C++ would help if Perl doesn't work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perl -ne ' print if /^d/i && /e$/i ' < words`

Since you are using Linux, it may be simpler to use grep(1):

`grep -i '^d.*e$' < words`

Comment: When you mention words, is that a value, could I print out the value using a command like this...? print "$words begin with d and e\n\n";

Comment: btw, the `<` is not required in either snippet. `^d.*e$` will also work in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

That's almost trivial in Perl:

```
$ perl -nE 'say "ok" if /^d.*e$/i'
Done
ok
Dish
Dome
ok
Death
```

It reads from STDIN and `say`s `ok` if the line matched. This is useful while debugging regular expressions. You just want to output matching lines, so you could simply replace  `say "ok"` by `say`

```
$ perl -nlE 'say if /^d.*e$/i' words
```

while `words` is the filename of your words file. It magically reads its lines. Short explanation of that regular expression match:

```
^    # start of the line
d    # the literal character 'd' (case-insensitive because of the i switch)
.*   # everything allowed here
$    # end of the line
```

Answer (score 2):

Not often I answer perl questions, but I think this does the trick.

```
my @words = ...;
@words = grep(/^d.*e$/i, @words);
```

grep uses a regular expression to filter the words.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;

for my $word (@ARGV) {

    if ( $word =~ m{\A d .* e \z}xmsi ) {

        print "$word\n";
    }
}
```